# Django socket connection timout

Tags: python, django, sockets, udp, lauterbach

I am trying to check if a certain device (Lauterbach PowerDebug Pro) is connected to the network. I have the following code that I am using in Django view.

```
    def checkConnection(hostname, port, timeout=5):
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        s.settimeout(timeout)
        message = bytes.fromhex('{1024 bytes here}')
        s.sendto(message,(hostname,port))
        try:
            if s.recv(1024):
                return True
        except ConnectionResetError:
            return False
        except socket.timeout:
            return False
```

If I run this function from the Django View (called through AJAX), it will return `False`.

If I run this code in a Python console, it will return `True`. If I run `manage.py shell` and manually write this code, it will return `True`.

However, if I run `manage.py shell`, import and call this function, it will return `False`, due to a timeout error.

How come? I can't figure out why it will not work. I have captured the messages using Wireshark and they are all the same. Below is the output.

Code written manually in Django shell (returned True):

> No.     Time           Source                Destination
>   Protocol Length Info
>       233 17.202222      10.171.90.59          10.171.94.100         UDP      1066   59221 → 60010 Len=1024
>
> Frame 233: 1066 bytes on wire (8528 bits), 1066 bytes captured (8528
>   bits) on interface 0 Ethernet II, Src: IntelCor_c1:d7:3e
>   (b4:6b:fc:c1:d7:3e), Dst: All-HSRP-routers_5a (00:00:0c:07:ac:5a)
>   Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 10.171.90.59, Dst: 10.171.94.100
>   User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 59221, Dst Port: 60010 Data (1024
>   bytes)
>
> 0000  03 01 01 00 62 ea 46 fd 54 52 41 43 45 33 32 00
>   ....b.F.TRACE32. 0010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0040  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0050  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0060  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0070  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0080  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0090  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 00a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 00b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 00c0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 00d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 00e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 00f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0100  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0110  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0120  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0130  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0140  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0150  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0160  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0170  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0180  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0190  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 01a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 01b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 01c0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 01d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 01e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 01f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0200  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0210  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0220  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0230  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0240  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0250  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0260  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0270  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0280  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0290  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 02a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 02b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 02c0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 02d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 02e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 02f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0300  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0310  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0320  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0330  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0340  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0350  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0360  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0370  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0380  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0390  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 03a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 03b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 03c0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 03d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 03e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 03f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................
>       Data: 0301010062ea46fd54524143453332000000000000000000…
>       [Length: 1024]
>
> No.     Time           Source                Destination
>   Protocol Length Info
>       234 17.220294      10.171.94.100         10.171.90.59          UDP      58     60002 → 59221 Len=16
>
> Frame 234: 58 bytes on wire (464 bits), 58 bytes captured (464 bits)
>   on interface 0 Ethernet II, Src: Cisco_74:52:0b (a4:6c:2a:74:52:0b),
>   Dst: IntelCor_c1:d7:3e (b4:6b:fc:c1:d7:3e) Internet Protocol Version
>   4, Src: 10.171.94.100, Dst: 10.171.90.59 User Datagram Protocol, Src
>   Port: 60002, Dst Port: 59221 Data (16 bytes)
>
> 0000  23 00 00 00 0a ab 5a 3b 54 52 41 43 45 33 32 00
>
> ## .....Z;TRACE32.
>
> ```
> Data: 230000000aab5a3b5452414345333200
> [Length: 16]
> ```

checkConnection function imported and ran in Django shell (returned True):

> No.     Time           Source                Destination
>   Protocol Length Info
>       437 53.946438      10.171.90.59          10.171.94.100         UDP      1066   59224 → 60010 Len=1024
>
> Frame 437: 1066 bytes on wire (8528 bits), 1066 bytes captured (8528
>   bits) on interface 0 Ethernet II, Src: IntelCor_c1:d7:3e
>   (b4:6b:fc:c1:d7:3e), Dst: All-HSRP-routers_5a (00:00:0c:07:ac:5a)
>   Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 10.171.90.59, Dst: 10.171.94.100
>   User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 59224, Dst Port: 60010 Data (1024
>   bytes)
>
> 0000  03 01 01 00 62 ea 46 fd 54 52 41 43 45 33 32 00
>   ....b.F.TRACE32. 0010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0040  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0050  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0060  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0070  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0080  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0090  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 00a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 00b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 00c0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 00d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 00e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 00f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0100  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0110  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0120  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0130  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0140  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0150  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0160  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0170  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0180  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0190  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 01a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 01b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 01c0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 01d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 01e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 01f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0200  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0210  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0220  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0230  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0240  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0250  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0260  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0270  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0280  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0290  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 02a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 02b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 02c0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 02d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 02e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 02f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0300  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0310  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0320  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0330  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0340  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0350  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0360  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0370  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0380  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 0390  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 03a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 03b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 03c0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 03d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 03e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................ 03f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ................
>       Data: 0301010062ea46fd54524143453332000000000000000000…
>       [Length: 1024]
>
> No.     Time           Source                Destination
>   Protocol Length Info
>       438 53.948831      10.171.94.100         10.171.90.59          UDP      58     60002 → 59224 Len=16
>
> Frame 438: 58 bytes on wire (464 bits), 58 bytes captured (464 bits)
>   on interface 0 Ethernet II, Src: Cisco_74:52:0b (a4:6c:2a:74:52:0b),
>   Dst: IntelCor_c1:d7:3e (b4:6b:fc:c1:d7:3e) Internet Protocol Version
>   4, Src: 10.171.94.100, Dst: 10.171.90.59 User Datagram Protocol, Src
>   Port: 60002, Dst Port: 59224 Data (16 bytes)
>
> 0000  23 00 00 00 0a ab 5a 3b 54 52 41 43 45 33 32 00
>
> ## .....Z;TRACE32.
>
> ```
> Data: 230000000aab5a3b5452414345333200
> [Length: 16]
> ```

So what gives?

Edit: It works for TCP connections (ex. checkConnection('10.11.12.13', 23) will return True). For some reason, only the UDP message will not be received.

In this case, checkConnection is:

```
    def checkConnection(hostname, port, timeout=5):
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.settimeout(timeout)
        try:
            s.connect((hostname, port))
            s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
            while True:
                try:
                    data = s.recv(1024)
                    if data:
                        s.close()
                        return True
        except socket.timeout:
            return False
        except TimeoutError:
            return False
        except ConnectionRefusedError:
            return False
        except ConnectionResetError:
            return False
```

Comment: Shouldnt message be defined before the sendto ?

Comment: @tomgalpin Yes, I made a mistake while pasting the code. I have corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the trick is to use [recvfrom()](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/manpages-dev/recvfrom.2.en.html) for UDP.

```
        try:
            data, address = s.recvfrom(1024)
            if data:
                return True
```

> **recv()**
>   The recv() call is normally used only on a connected socket (see [connect(2)](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/manpages-dev/connect.2.en.html)). 
>   It is equivalent to the call:
>
> recvfrom(fd, buf, len, flags, NULL, 0);

I still don't understand why `recv()` worked in all situations, except running from a Django view.